# What does 'getProductaf' mean?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use codeigniter, and I use the code below in a view to show a new Windows form. I don't understand what is 'getProductaf' mean?

I search in whole folder controllers, models and view there is empty function named 'getProductaf'.
Do you guys know something?

```
function getproduct(obj) {
    var val = obj.name;
    var index = val.split("_")[1];
    var idnopo =document.getElementsByName("idnopo_0")[0].value; 
window.open('<?php echo base_url()."index.php/menuppic/get_productpo?index=";?>'+index+'&idnopo='+idnopo,'getProductaf','addressbar=0,location=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1');
}
```

Comment: The code you shared looks like javascript and so is not part of CodeIgniter.

Comment: i use this code in view. so do u got any idea what is that mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
function getproduct(obj) {
    var val = obj.name;
    var index = val.split("_")[1];
    var idnopo =document.getElementsByName("idnopo_0")[0].value;  window.open('<?php echo base_url()."index.php/menuppic/get_productpo?index=";?>'+index+'&idnopo='+idnopo,***'getProductaf'***,'addressbar=0,location=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1'); }
```

what is this and where r u using the function........

Comment: in your last line watch carefully ..........'getProductaf', addressbar=0,location=0..................

Answer (score 0):

If you check your `window.open(strURL, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures])` structure, you'll conclude it is window name.

> A string name for the new window. The name can be used as the target of links and forms using the target attribute of an  or  element. The name should not contain any whitespace characters. Note that strWindowName does not specify the title of the new window.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Return_value_and_parameters).